# Html5 ajax file upload progress listener not triggering when upload 100% on Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax-upload

I am uploading files over ajax and processing images after upload.
When I tried upload image files over ajax on firefox , xhr progress event not triggering my progress function when upload percent do 100% but file was uploading successfully .

Google chrome triggering when upload progress 100% but firefox doesn't.

Biriefly my upload script :

```
$("#uploadbutton").click(function(){
   var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
   ,fd=new FormData();

   xhr.upload.addEventListener("loadstart", uploadStart, false);
   xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
   xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);

   xhr.open("POST", mainurl+"ajaxupload.php");

   $.each($("#upload_input").files,function(i,file){
     fd.append("files_"+i,file);
   });    

  xhr.send(fd);

});

function uploadProgress(event){
   var percentComplete = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
   console.log("pecent ",percentComplete);
}
```

When upload start , uploadProgress function runnig 1 times ( mostly when upload percent 80% ), but not triggering when upload fnish .

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your current handlers, add two more: [load](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#suggested-names-for-events-using-the-progressevent-interface) (fires if successful completion), [loadend](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#suggested-names-for-events-using-the-progressevent-interface) (fires last, always).

```js
// zero or once
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadSuccess, false);
function uploadSuccess(event) {
    console.log("Upload successful.");
}

// once
xhr.addEventListener("loadend", uploadComplete, false);
function uploadComplete(event) {
    console.log("All done.");
}
```

Comment: I am adding load listener to the xhr but it is not triggering listener function never.

Comment: I tried the "load" listener after you say.At [load](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#suggested-names-for-events-using-the-progressevent-interface) usage writes "load" listener fires "zero or once", When load listener fires once,when zero ?

Comment: Fires "load" if upload was successful, then fires a "loadend".  If not successful, just "loadend" is fired.  I've updated the answer.